# Смена Placeholder на новый текст (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple

подскажите пожалуйста, есть текстовое поле textView с плейсхолдером, когда я нажимаю любую букву с клавиатуры, текст плейсхолдера пропадает, но что б появилась буква нужно еще раз нажать. Как это исправить? к сожалению еще не разобрался в swift, но попросили пофиксить этот баг.(

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if doneButton.isHidden {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4352941176, green: 0.4431372549, blue: 0.4745098039, alpha: 1)

        doneButton.isHidden = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите метод делегата textView:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText = textView.text! as NSString
    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
    doneLabel.isHidden = (newText.length > 0)
    return true
}
```